# In Rails 5, is there a functional difference between "model.save" and "model.errors.empty?"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.  I have this logic in my controller ...

```
@user = UserService.create_user(params)
if @user.errors.empty?
  render :create, :status => :ok
```

Is there any difference between the above and

```
@user = UserService.create_user(params)
if @user.save
  render :create, :status => :ok
```

I'm trying to decide whether to use ".save" or ".errors.empty?" logic.

Comment: Those are different things. What's `create_user` suppose to do? What does it return? `save` creates or updates the record if valid, while errors returns the errors object after validating the receiver.

Comment: @SebastianPalma `create_user`  is most likely the method generated by `belongs_to :user`. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: Ups, just thought it was a "service" class implementing a class method `create_user`, thanks @max.

Comment: @SebastianPalma actually that sounds more likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are just inferior ways of doing:

```
@user = UserService.build_user(params) # just instanciate the record
if @user.save
   # ...
else
   # ...
end
```

Is there a functional difference? Yes. `.save` triggers all the callbacks on the model related to saving the record which could have side effects. If you want to to just check if it was saved use `.persisted?`. `.errors.empty?` is a bad imitation of `.valid?`.

Neither of the two will blow anything up but it still bugs me as it makes your intent much less clear. And it also creates two queries (and trigger update callbacks) if you do something like:

```
@user = UserService.create_user(params)
@user.foo = bar
if @user.save
   # ...
else
   # ...
end
```

Which is really common when you want to merge parameters with information from elsewhere like the session.

`render :create, status: :ok` is also just weird. Usually you want to just redirect to the newly created resource as that bumps the history so that the browser actually goes back to the right page instead of `/users` if the user hits the back button. For an api you can respond with `status: :created, location: @user` or a JSON representation of the resource.

Comment: When you say "And it also create two queries", which two queries are those?

Comment: Sorry the example was a bit off. But if you save the record at `@user = UserService.create_user(params)` and then update an attribute and the call `.save` you will create both an INSERT and UPDATE query instead of just a single INSERT query.

Comment: If this is a service object and you want to move persistence inside of it you should check `.persisted?` as there is one key functional difference I missed. `errors.empty?` or `valid?` just checks if the application level validations passed. It does not guarantee that the record was actually inserted in the database.